# How to load external JSON data in vue.js

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2

I wrote a component showing some images and when you click it a  modal popup show more information.

Data displayed on dialog are in `json` format embedded in the component, now I want that data will retrieve from some external link.

Here you can see an example of [Json Data File](http://ideazfactory.in/library/jj.json) and here the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/niskhu01/pen/jOOEEYE)

```js
// global component
Vue.component("my-car", {
  template: "#car-info",
  props: {
    active: "active",
    isActive: "isActive",
    carlist: "carlist",
    show: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      twoWay: true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    // check which content index is active
    modalActiveContent: function(i) {
       return this.active === i
    },
    // close modal
    setModalClose: function() {
     this.show = false;
      //if need set active content to zero object       
     // this.active = 0;
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    active: 0,
    showModal: false,
    cars: [
    {
      img: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/qN73wDiyplutRKOHiXaLYFgPhwK.jpg",
      title: "Default",
      description: "lorem lorem lorem."
    },{
       img: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/tWBo7aZk3I1dLxmMj7ZJcN8uke5.jpg",
      title: "Citroen",
      description: "Lorem ipsum."
    }, {
       img: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/qN73wDiyplutRKOHiXaLYFgPhwK.jpg",
      title: "Honda",
      description: "Lorem ipsum lorem lorem."
    }
]
  }, 
  methods: {
    // set active modal and set index which content is activated
    modalOpen: function(i) {
        this.showModal = true; 
        return this.active = i;
      }
  }
});
```

```css
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: table;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.modal-header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #42b983;
}

.modal-body {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.modal-default-button {
  float: right;
}

/*
 * the following styles are auto-applied to elements with
 * v-transition="modal" when their visibility is toggled
 * by Vue.js.
 *
 * You can easily play with the modal transition by editing
 * these styles.
 */

.modal-enter, .modal-leave {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-enter .modal-container,
.modal-leave .modal-container {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <img src="{{car.img}}" alt="{{car.title}}" class="demo-img" v-for="car in cars" id="show-modal" @click="modalOpen($index)">
      
    
 
  <my-car :show.sync="showModal" :carlist="cars" :active.sync="active"></my-car>
<!-- Var dump data -->
</div>
 
<template id="car-info">
  <div  class="modal-mask" v-show="show" transition="modal" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-describedBy="modalDescription" style="border: 2px solid black;">
    <div class="modal-container">
    <h4>Detailed View1</h4>
  <div class="car-item" v-for="car in carlist" v-if="modalActiveContent($index)">
    <img src="{{car.img}}" alt="{{car.title}}">
      <h1>{{car.title}}</h1>
      <p>{{car.description}}</p>
     <button v-if="modalActiveContent($index)" class="modal-default-button"
              @click="setModalClose">
              Close me please
            </button>
  </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: please help me , how to add external json link in above code , also check external json link and my codepen link too. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Data provided with your file is not in JSON format

[JSON syntax](https://json.org/)

[JSON syntax with W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp)

2. If you want to fetch data from external link use **axios**

[npm - axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

[cdn - axios](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.19.0/index.min.js)

```
axios.get('/path-to-json-dataset')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

```
axios.get('http://ideazfactory.in/library/jj.json')
  .then(function (response) {
    this.cars = response.data;
  })
```

Comment: thanks for your time !

but what i want is to show the data in my vue.js script that come from external link

Comment: @NishantKhullar you can fetch JSON data with axios and then assign it to **data** cars array.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Vue code as follows. (and ofc don't forget `npm i axios --save` or the yarn equivalent.

```
import axios from 'axios'

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    active: 0,
    showModal: false,
    cars: []
  }, 
  methods: {
    // set active modal and set index wich content is activeted
    modalOpen: function(i) {
        this.showModal = true; 
        return this.active = i;
      }
  },
  created(): {
    axios.get('http://http://ideazfactory.in/library/jj.json')
      .then(response => {
         this.cars = response;
      }
  }
});
```

Note there is some issue with the JSON being returned from the url you provided, it is giving me an invalid JSON error on my browser. Created is a lifecycle hook that is called when Vue instance is initialized. You can run functions here for data fetching, it is called before the view is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `mounted` function to load external json data as below.

```
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Code that will run only after the
    // entire view has been rendered
    // Make a request for a user with a given ID
    axios.get('http://ideazfactory.in/library/jj.json')
        .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
        this.cars = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: not working with my code , no data retrieve from file

Comment: It may lacks of axios dependency. How do you send http request?